# Displaying weather widget based on click using Apache Cordova and https://weatherwidget.io/?

Tags: javascript, cordova

I am making a Cordova project where I am displaying a Google Maps via API call and it has 2 buttons. One button shows one lat/long, and the other shows another lat/long. Each button is linked to display a weather forecast which is gotten from https://weatherwidget.io/. I would like for each of the widgets to display only for the lat/long selected. The first time a button is clicked, it will display both the widgets, and only after this will the widgets react normally. I cannot seem to find where the issue is in my code. Even if I set the style to "none" initially in my script, it will show both widgets, and then it will work normally. How can I fix this?

Here is the code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      document.addEventListener(
        "deviceready",
        function () {
          let div = document.getElementById("map_canvas");

          // Create a Google Maps native view under the map_canvas div.
          let map = plugin.google.maps.Map.getMap(div);

          // If you click the button, do something...
          let buttonZG = document.getElementById("buttonZG");
          let buttonDU = document.getElementById("buttonDU");
          let zgWeather = document.getElementById("zgWeather");
          let duWeather = document.getElementById("duWeather");

          buttonZG.addEventListener("click", function () {
            // Move to the position with animation
            !(function (d, s, id) {
              let js,
                fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
              if (!d.getElementById(id)) {
                js = d.createElement(s);
                js.id = id;
                js.src = "https://weatherwidget.io/js/widget.min.js";
                fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
              }
            })(document, "script", "weatherwidget-io-js");

            map.animateCamera({
              target: { lat: 45.7825, lng: 15.9812 },
              zoom: 17,
              tilt: 60,
              bearing: 140,
              duration: 5000,
            });
            duWeather.style.display = "none";
            zgWeather.style.display = "block";
            // Add a maker
            let markerZG = map.addMarker({
              position: { lat: 45.7825, lng: 15.9812 },
              title: "This is where \n" + "RIT Croatia Zagreb is located.",
              snippet: "It is very close to Bundek.",
              animation: plugin.google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE,
            });

            // Show the info window

            markerZG.showInfoWindow();
          });

          buttonDU.addEventListener("click", function () {
            zgWeather.style.display = "none";
            !(function (d, s, id) {
              let js,
                fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
              if (!d.getElementById(id)) {
                js = d.createElement(s);
                js.id = id;
                js.src = "https://weatherwidget.io/js/widget.min.js";
                fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
              }
            })(document, "script", "weatherwidget-io-js");
            // Move to the position with animation
            map.animateCamera({
              target: { lat: 45.7825, lng: 15.9812 },
              zoom: 17,
              tilt: 60,
              bearing: 140,
              duration: 5000,
            });
            duWeather.style.display = "block";
            zgWeather.style.display = "none";
            // Add a maker
            let markerDU = map.addMarker({
              position: { lat: 42.642, lng: 18.1029 },
              title: "This is where \n" + "RIT Croatia Dubrovnik is located.",
              snippet: "It it a beautiful town.",
              animation: plugin.google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE,
            });

            // Show the info window
            markerDU.showInfoWindow();
          });
        },
        false
      );
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
      #map_canvas {
        /* Must bigger size than 100x100 pixels */
        width: 100%;
        height: 500px;
      }
      button {
        padding: 0.5em;
        margin: 0.5em;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>RIT Croatia Stats</h1>
    <div id="map_canvas">
      <button id="buttonZG">Go to RIT Croatia Zagreb</button>
      <button id="buttonDU">Go to RIT Croatia Dubrovnik</button>
    </div>
    <a
      id="zgWeather"
      class="weatherwidget-io"
      href="https://forecast7.com/en/45d8215d98/zagreb/"
      data-label_1="ZAGREB"
      data-label_2="WEATHER"
      data-theme="original"
    ></a>
    <a
      id="duWeather"
      class="weatherwidget-io"
      href="https://forecast7.com/en/42d6518d09/dubrovnik/"
      data-label_1="DUBROVNIK"
      data-label_2="WEATHER"
      data-theme="original"
    ></a>
  </body>
</html>
```